# Rename environment variable key

Tags: environment-variables

I have following environment variable `OLD_KEY=value` and want to rename the env var name so it is `KEY=value`.

Already tryied `export KEY=${${OLD_KEY}}`.

Anyone who has an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Is a POSIX shell, like bash, you dereference a variable with a single dollar-sign. So this is all you need:

```
export KEY="$OLD_KEY"
```

The double-quotes are always a good idea, even if you don't think they're needed due to quirks of the POSIX shell standard. Specifically, how variable expansion interacts with `$IFS`.

P.S., You should have told us which shell (or language) you're using rather than make us guess.